# Postgres – how to alter the WHERE clause of a postgres index

Tags: postgresql, performance, index

I need to insert a new two-field index on an existing table with about 600 million rows in it. The table contains data accumulated over about a year with approximately 2 million new rows added per day.

I know adding a new index to one very large table in one go will take ages, so to save time I started by only indexing the last few days worth of data using the following command…

```
CREATE INDEX  idx_001
ON message (deviceNumber, messageTime)
WHERE messageTime >='07-May-2018 00:00:00' ;
```

This took about 3 hours, or about 40 minutes to index one day.

Ideally I’d like to index the whole table, but at 40 minutes for a days data doing it on one go will take over a week.

I guess I could create lots of small indexes, each for a few days of data, maybe something like this…

```
CREATE INDEX  idx_002
ON message (deviceNumber, messageTime)
WHERE messageTime <'07-May-2018 00:00:00' AND messageTime >='01-May-2018 00:00:00'  ;
```

But I’d prefer to stick with one index. Is there any way of ALTERing the where clause of the existing index to increase the days covered? Or do I have to create lots of small indexes?

Comment: In addition to @FedericoRazzoli's answer, that seems like a ridiculous amount of time to index 9 million rows.  You should probably investigate why it takes so long.

Comment: you're keeping this data forever?  if not this may be a good time to consider partitioning using sql inheritance.

Comment: Why are you using these (weirdly formatted) strings,  ie. `'07-May-2018 00:00:00'` and not using a standard format, like `'2018-05-07 00:00:00'`?

Comment: @ypercube - explicitly stating 'May' leaves no room for error. Using '2018-05-07' allows for potential confusion between american/european users who follow different conventions.

Comment: No, that's the ISO standard format. Nothing ambiguous about it. See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-DATE-TABLE

Comment: @ypercube. Not everyone uses ISO standard format. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-DATE-TABLE for some other date formats. The characters 'May' are unlikely to mistaken for any other month.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot alter an index. Because, even if PostgreSQL allowed this, it would need to rebuild the index anyway. Unless it implemented very smart checks on the `WHERE` clause, which would serve quite rare use cases.

Having many indexes is also not optimal. Every time you run a query, the planner has to consider all existing indexes and pick up the best one. If you have several indexes, the planner takes more time. Not ages - but still, this delay affects each and every query involving that table.

My suggestion is... be patient and build a big index. You can use `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` to avoid locks.